# VBA- filter unecessary folders

Tags: vba, filter, directory

I have a question about reading files within folders. I found this code:

```
sub sample()
    Dim FileSystem As Object
    Dim HostFolder As String

    HostFolder = "C:\"

    Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)
end  sub

Sub DoFolder(Folder)
    Dim SubFolder
    For Each SubFolder In Folder.SubFolders
        DoFolder SubFolder
    Next
    Dim File
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        ' Operate on each file
    Next
End Sub
```

But how would you go about avoiding a specific folder which is within the original one?
Let's say the you have a folder A which in turn has several folder Bs. within these folders, there are the file required but also another folder, always with the same name, let's say C.

How would you filter out folders Cs?

Thank you for your time

Comment: Do you always know the name of the folder you want to filter out?

Comment: `If  SubFolder.Name <> "C" Then DoFolder SubFolder`

Comment: @JeremyHodge yes, the name is/will be padronized

Comment: @TimWilliams is that enough to skip over the "filtered" folder?

Comment: It should be - did you try it? Note it will filter out *any* folder with that name (and so all of it contents) at any level in the folder tree.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
' List of complete path of files in folder / subfolders
' Needs to add "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" reference to your file
Sub FolderFilesPath(ByVal pFolder As String, ByRef pColFiles As Collection, _
    Optional ByVal pGetSubFolders As Boolean, Optional ByVal pFilter As Collection)
    Dim sFolder As String
    Dim oFSO As New FileSystemObject
    Dim oFolder, oSubFolder As Folder
    Dim oFile As File
    
    sFolder = IIf(Right(pFolder, 1) <> "\", pFolder & "\", pFolder)
    Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolder)
    If Not ExistsInCollection(pFilter, sFolder) Then
        For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
            pColFiles.Add oFile
        Next oFile
        If pGetSubFolders Then
            For Each oSubFolder In oFolder.SubFolders
                FolderFilesPath oSubFolder.Path, pColFiles, pGetSubFolders, pFilter
            Next
        End If
    End If
End Sub

' Vba collection contains
Function ExistsInCollection(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo err
    ExistsInCollection = True
    IsObject (col.Item(key))
    Exit Function
err:
    ExistsInCollection = False
End Function
'------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Sub TestMe()
    Dim colFiles As New Collection, sFilePath As Variant
    Dim colExcludedFolders As New Collection
    Dim sHostFolder As String
    
    sHostFolder = "C:\temp"
    With colExcludedFolders
        ' add folders you want to exclude
        .Add sHostFolder & "\C\", sHostFolder & "\C\"
    End With
    FolderFilesPath ThisWorkbook.Path, colFiles, True, colExcludedFolders
    ' colFiles contains filtered files
    For Each sFilePath In colFiles
        With sFilePath
            ' do what you want with filtered files
            Debug.Print .Path & " - " & .Name & " - " & .DateCreated
        End With
    Next sFilePath
End Sub
```